PyInstaller getting error when opening .exe ModuleNotFoundError: tkinter
I am building a py file into exe using PyInstaller. Whenever I try to open the .exe, I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_gui.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

I tried every solution I could find online:

Tried using the --hidden-import flag with tkinter and rebuilding
Tried adding tkinter to the hidden imports in the .spec file
Tried removing the excludeimport tkinter from the hooks in the Lib/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks

Nothing I have tried works. Still getting the same error

It means that the Python environment which PyInstaller uses does not have tkinter installed.
